# How does Steam handle compatibility

Tags: compilation, compatibility, software-design, steam

I'm new to the development world, primarily targeted towards game development, and I want to know more about how software becomes compatible across all architectures.

I've read information on the subject and there appears two ways that I have read:

-Compile the resources for the individual architectures.

-Have a Virtual Machine or interpreter run the application.

So it left me wondering about game content delivery systems like Steam, and how they handle this issue.

Does Steam have the resources compiled for each architecture and chooses between which one it sends to the client depending on the client's operating system and architecture?

Is there something else I'm missing?

How does software compatibility work? and how do developers (such as indie developers) overcome this issue?

Comment: Seems to me Steam acts primarily as a distribution platform, probably with a cross-plat API that games can use to hook into the friends services etc. So it's probably up to the individual developer to put out versions for different OS'es however they choose. A lot of games seem to only be available on PC.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I appreciate it. 

However, taking what you said, I'm still not sure I understand.

At the lowest level, with no abstraction, how does multi platforming and software compatibility work exactly.

As a hopeful future independent game developer, I am asking whether I would have to have access to several different architectures for each version, to claim it runs on Windows? or is there someway of using one machine to create a architecture independent application?

Comment: Depends how different the platforms are. If it's the same OS on different processor, you can probably just recompile the same code for the 2nd platform. If it's different OS, you'll have to rewrite any code that depends on OS specific functionality e.g. window management. If it's a platform that doesn't even support the same programming language, you have to write completely new code. There are many cross-platform libraries that have implementations for the same functionality in different OS so you don't have to completely rewrite, i.e. for graphics.